# .NET Tab panel using repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabpanel, asprepeater

Need Help.
I am using a asp:repeater to load the Header, Sub List and urls required in a tab panel in an aspx page.
When I render this in the page I get the Tab Panel headers and the links associated with it as sub list.
I have around 7 tabs and each contains its own sub links
The issue here is that when the repeater loads the tab panels I am  not able to click on the tab panel headers other than the first one. The first tab loads the data and links related to it. 
When I click on the Tab headers of the rest 6 am not able to navigate. It just loads as a text.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrCMCUrls" runat="server" > 
    <HeaderTemplate> <%--<li id="tabpanel_1" class="tabpanel_default">--%>
        <li id="tabpanel_1" class="tabpanel_default">
            <a onclick="tabpanel_click1;" class="tab_link" style="cursor:pointer">
                <%#displayGroup(STR_CMC_GRP)%></a>
            <ul id="tabpanel_1_sublist" class="list_decorative_dark"></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>‌​<li><%#getNavBarUrl(‌​Container.DataItem)%‌​></a></li></ItemTemp‌​late><FooterTemplate >
    </FooterTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: What you had tried so far? Share your code.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="rptrCMCUrls" runat="server" >
<HeaderTemplate>    <%--<li id="tabpanel_1" class="tabpanel_default">--%><li id="tabpanel_1" class="tabpanel_default"><a onclick="tabpanel_click1;" class="tab_link" style="cursor:pointer"><%#displayGroup(STR_CMC_GRP)%></a><ul id="tabpanel_1_sublist" class="list_decorative_dark"></HeaderTemplate><ItemTemplate><li><%#getNavBarUrl(Container.DataItem)%></a></li></ItemTemplate><FooterTemplate ></FooterTemplate></asp:Repeater>

Comment: I don't think your code is correct. Reverify your tags.